# Какие оптимальные практики работы с электорнными письмами

Tags: html

Есть проблема в компании с верстками писем, постоянно какие-либо почтовые клиенты не отображают части версток, процесс дебага достаточно трудоемкий.
Какие практики вы знаете по оптимизации создания и верстки писем, возможно какие-либо сервисы, которые позволяют делегировать эту работу, например на контентщиков

Comment: писать письма обычным текстом. Самый классный и надежный вариант. Если клиент не отображает такое письмо - это уже проблема клиента, а не письма

Answer (score 2):

Есть всего 2 правила, какие я вывел для себя. По сути, это мои субъективные практики, возможно есть и что-то лучшее.

1. Табличная верстка
2. Все стили прописываются в тегах, не вынося в голову.

Эти 2 правила сэкономили мне кучу времени и нервов.

P.S.: Ну и путь к картинкам вставлять полный https://site.com/image.png

Answer (score 0):

Все как обычно. Отправить письмо есть несколько вариантов, а точнее 2.

1. Текстовое сообщение
2. Html контент.

Проблем думаю с текстовым поменьше, но и там работы контенщикам можно будет найти. Интересен вариант html так как его содержимое это страница со стилями и заполнением, пусть и не со всеми [тегами](https://medium.com/@ranadeepbhuyan/supported-html-tags-in-common-email-clients-2cc11e1ae283). Конечно основной интерес представляет шаблоны писем которые генерируются по шаблонам и данным. Можно посмотреть просторы интернета и найти массу генераторов писем в зависимости от используемого бекенда